# Cech cohomology (Harthshorne)

Tags: algebraic-geometry, homology-cohomology, sheaf-cohomology

I´m studying Cech cohomology through Hartshorne´s algebraic geometry and EGA, and I´m stuck in two exercises, I wonder if you can help me. The first one is the exercise III.4.4, we want to prove that
$$\varinjlim_{\mathfrak{U}}\check{H}^{1}(\mathfrak{U},\mathcal{F})=H^{1}(X,\mathcal{F})$$
where $\mathfrak{U}$ is a covering of $X$. (I attach a photo of the exercise)
[Exercise III. 4.4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9WjVt.jpg)

I have just proved $a)$ and $b)$.

I´m also stuck with the last exercise of this section: Let $X$ be a topological spaces, $\mathcal{F}$ a sheaf of abelian groups, and $\mathfrak{U}=(U_{i})$ an open cover. Assume for any finite intersection $V=U_{i_{0}}\cap\cdots\cap U_{i_{p}}$ of open sets of the covering, and for any $k>0$, that $H^{k}(V,\mathcal{F}_{\mid V})=0$. Then prove that for all $p\geq 0$, the natural maps 
$$\check{H}^{p}(\mathfrak{U},\mathcal{F})\rightarrow H^{p}(X,\mathcal{F})$$
of the last exercise (III. 4.4) are isomorphisms.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I follow the hint there and adapt the notations.
For the statement (c), you can take the long exact sequence of the sequence of the complex $0\to C^\bullet(\mathfrak{U},\mathcal{F})\to C^\bullet(\mathfrak{U},\mathcal{G})\to D^\bullet(\mathfrak{U})\to 0$. This gives you

$$0\to \check{H}^0(\mathfrak{U},\mathcal{F})\to \check{H}^0(\mathfrak{U},\mathcal{G})\to H^0(D^\bullet(\mathfrak{U}))\to \check{H}^1(\mathfrak{U},\mathcal{F})\to 0.$$

$\check{H}^1(\mathfrak{U},\mathcal{G})=0$ since $\mathcal{G}$ is flasque.

Also you have isomorphisms $\check{H}^0(\mathfrak{U},\mathcal{F})\cong\Gamma(X,\mathcal{F})$ and $\check{H}^0(\mathfrak{U},\mathcal{G})\cong\Gamma(X,\mathcal{G})$ as well as a natural map $H^0(D^\bullet(\mathfrak{U}))\to \check{H}^0(\mathfrak{U},\mathcal{R})=\Gamma(X,\mathcal{R})$. These fit together and give the following commutative diagram:

$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
0@>>> \check{H}^0(\mathfrak{U},\mathcal{F})@>>> \check{H}^0(\mathfrak{U},\mathcal{G})@>>> H^0(D^\bullet(\mathfrak{U}))@>>> \check{H}^1(\mathfrak{U},\mathcal{F})@>>> 0\\
@. @VVV @VVV @VVV \\
0@>>>\Gamma(X,\mathcal{F})@>>> \Gamma(X,\mathcal{G})@>>> \Gamma(X,\mathcal{R})@>>> H^1(X,\mathcal{F})@>>> 0
\end{CD}

So you have an induced map $\check{H}^1(\mathfrak{U},\mathcal{F})\to H^1(X,\mathcal{F})$. Now take the direct limit (with respect to the open cover) in the first line. The result will follow if we can show 
$$
\varinjlim_{\mathfrak{U}} H^0(D^\bullet(\mathfrak{U}))\cong H^0(X,\mathcal{R}).
$$
The injectivity is obvious. For surjectivity, from the definition of quotient sheaves, for any $r\in \Gamma(X,\mathcal{R})$, $r$ can be described by giving an open cover $\mathfrak{V}=\{V_i\}$ of $X$ and elements $g_i\in \Gamma(V_i,\mathcal{G})$ such that $g_i-g_j\in\Gamma(V_i\cap V_j,\mathcal{F})$. Hence the sujectivity follows.

For the last exercise, you can imitate the proof of **Theorem 4.5**. Instead of the affineness of the open sets, the condition on the vanishing of higher cohomologies in the exercise implies that you still have the short exact sequence
$$
0\to \mathcal{F}(U_{i_0\cdots i_p})\to \mathcal{G}(U_{i_0\cdots i_p})\to \mathcal{R}(U_{i_0\cdots i_p})\to 0
$$
and hence the short exact sequence of Cech complexes. The same argument will work. You need the vanishing assumption here again for the induction step.

Answer (score 1):

Prove that

> $(*)$ under refinement $D^*(\mathfrak U) \to C^*(\mathfrak U, \mathscr R)$ induces an isomorphism on $h^0$.

Use that locally a section of $\mathscr R$ lifts to a section of $\mathscr G$.

Then you get an exact sequence, $$H^0(X, \mathscr G) \to H^0(X,\mathscr R) \to \check H^1(X,\mathscr F) \to 0.$$
Note $H^1(X,\mathscr F) = \text{coker}\left( H^0(X,\mathscr G) \to H^0(X,\mathscr R)\right)$.

Comment: I dont have any idea about how to prove that

Comment: To show (*) is a surjection on $h^0$ I just need to know that any section of $\mathscr R$ can locally be lifted to a section of $\mathscr G$. Do you think so?